# How To Work With MVC Architecture in VBA/Access

Tags: oop, vba, model-view-controller

i'd like to know how to work with Model View Controller architecture in VBA language. I want to know where the Model code, the View code and the Controller code goes into the VBA/Access structure. I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interresting question indeed ; though broad ... I'd suggest you tell us how you would do it, and why it isn't satisfying.

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question. I was working on cross migrations. C#.Net, VB, VBA, Java. We noticed, VBA was the point most typical OOP developers hit rock. Confusing & bizzare. [Check this out](http://www.haslo.ch/blog/whats-wrong-with-vba-13/)